# Inject function into Webpack like the DefinePlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-plugin

I want to communicate between a loader and my runtime code. Specifically I want to write a loader that stores all CSS that has been loaded in a variable that I can read out in my runtime. Here is some dummy code to illustrate:

***myLoader.js***

```
module.exports = function(content) {
    // This should store the content accessible to the runtime code
    storeCss(content);
    return content;
};
```

***app.js***

```
// This should load the CSS as stored by the loader
const css = getStoredCss();
```

For instance with the `webpack.DefinePlugin` I can do this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  SOME_GLOBALLY_AVAILABLE_CONST: JSON.stringify('my value'),
}),
```

Now in both, my loader and my runtime code I can access `SOME_GLOBALLY_AVAILABLE_CONST` and get `'my value'`. Is it possible to write a plugin that does the same thing but implements `storeCss` and `getStoredCss` so I can access them in my loader and my runtime code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this now with the new DefinePlugin.**runtimeValue**.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    STORED_CSS: webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue(
        function () { return JSON.stringify(getStoredCss()) }, []
    )
})
```

**app.js**

```js
const css = STORED_CSS
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  SOME_GLOBALLY_AVAILABLE_FUNCTION_THAT_PROBABLY_SHOULDNT_BE_ALL_CAPS: require('./myLoader.js').toString(),
}),
```